# JRuby script with Rubeus and Swing exiting once packaged into jar using warble

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jruby, jframe

I am trying to package a simple JRuby script into a jar file.
The script uses **Rubeus::Swing** and runs correctly when executed with the JRuby interpreter.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubeus'

class Example01
  extend Rubeus::Swing
  def show
    JFrame.new("Rubeus Swing Example 01") do |frame|
      frame.visible = true
    end
  end
end
Example01.new.show
```

Once I package the script into a JAR with `warble`, when I execute:

```
java -jar jtest.jar
```

... the JFrame window shows up and instantly closes.

There is no indication of errors of any kind.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Warbler calls System.exit() after your main script exits. This causes the Swing EventThread to exit, closing your app.

https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/ext/JarMain.java#L131

I worked around this problem by joining with the event thread at the bottom of my start script like so:

```
event_thread = nil
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait { event_thread = java.lang.Thread.currentThread }
event_thread.join
```

Hacky, but it works.

Comment: A more complete sample is here for Ben's Excellent fix. [Example Gist](https://gist.github.com/patrickjonesdotca/5075104)

Answer (score 1):

Just set the appropriate flag:

```
System.setProperty("warbler.skip_system_exit","true");
```