# Swing application closes right away after launch

Tags: java, swing, jruby

I have a simple JRuby Swing application, wich compiled and packed to jar using Warbler. After executing jar file, Swing frame appears and closes right away.

```
include Java

import java.awt.Font
import javax.swing.JFrame
import javax.swing.JPanel
import javax.swing.JLabel

class Main
def initialize
@logInWin = JFrame.new
    basic = JPanel.new

    font = Font.new "Verdana", Font::PLAIN, 16

    loginL = JLabel.new "Login"
    loginL.setFont font

    basic.add loginL
    @logInWin.add basic
    @logInWin.pack

    @logInWin.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame::EXIT_ON_CLOSE
    @logInWin.setSize 350, 350
    @logInWin.setLocationRelativeTo nil
    @logInWin.setTitle "Log In"
    @logInWin.setVisible true
end
end

Main.new
```

How do I avoid this behaviour?

**Environment:**

OS: Win 8

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

jruby 9.0.0.0.rc1 (2.2.2) 2015-06-10 a0bf3b3 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.11-b03 on 1.8.0_11-b12 +jit [Windows 8-amd64]

Warbler version 1.4.8

Comment: Please state at least a true question (which is "how do I avoid this behaviour", I assume...). And maybe give some context (OS ?, version ?, ...)

Comment: @kebs, Question and Enironment info are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question already exists:
[JRuby script with Rubeus and Swing exiting once packaged into jar using warble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108822/jruby-script-with-rubeus-and-swing-exiting-once-packaged-into-jar-using-warble)

> Add at the bottom of the main script:
>
> ```
> event_thread = nil
> SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait { event_thread = java.lang.Thread.currentThread }
> event_thread.join
> ```